# How to use id-aes256-GCM with Node.JS crypto? "TypeError: DecipherFinal fail"

Tags: javascript, security, node.js, cryptography, express

I want to encrypt some data in Node.js using an authenticated encryption scheme like AES-GCM.

If I run the following sample code

```
app.get("/test", function(req,res)  {
  var key = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
  var iv = "123456789012"; 
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("id-aes256-GCM",key.toString("binary"),iv.toString("binary"));
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("id-aes256-GCM",key.toString("binary"),iv.toString("binary"));

  console.log(decipher.update(cipher.update("bla")));
  console.log(decipher.update(cipher.final()));
  console.log(decipher.final());
});
```

I don't get a console output but the error message "TypeError: DecipherFinal fail".
If I use cipher AES-256-CTR instead of "id-aes256-GCM", this code works fine and prints "bla" on the console.

What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**

Further investigating shows, that cipher.update("bla") returns "â" (single character...strange) and cipher.final() returns an empty string. I think this can't be a correct ciphertext which should at least have the size of the plaintext...

Comment: What is the size of the returned ciphertext of `cipher.update("bla")` and `cipher.final()` ?

Comment: I edited the question to answer it

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - I meant that I answered YOUR question with the edit. Unfortunatelly I don't have access to a pc with the id-aes256-GCM encryption scheme for the next 3 weeks, so I'll test your suggestion cipher.update("bla","binary","hex") then.

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry for the remark on the misunderstanding. Note that people may not take a look at the comments after reading the submission. I'll be here if you have the output (make a remark and put my name into it like this: @owlstead, otherwise I may miss the change).

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is an issue with OpenSSL. Issuing `echo -n "bla" | openssl enc -e -id-aes256-GCM -nosalt -a -out t.out` followed by `openssl enc -d -id-aes256-GCM -nosalt -a -in t.out` yields the error `bad decrypt`. Maybe a bug in OpenSSL?

Comment: I can't even get to the fail part above, getting "node-crypto : Unknown cipher id-aes256-GCM" on 0.8.9.

Comment: Cipher text is binary. It depends on the used [tag:character-encoding] what you will see in text. Thats why it is useful to base 64 encode the result if you want to send it, or base 16 (hexadecimals) if you want to show the binary contents.

Comment: GCM requires extra parameters, which NodeJS can possibly not give to OpenSSL. See this thread/link: http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg68932.html

Comment: Sorry, but aren't you missing the auth tag completely? GCM requires a sort of 'hash' named auth tag, to decipher correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCM mode in OpenSSL works fine. It has been tested with other implementations as well. I know for a fact that the [PolarSSL SSL library](https://polarssl.org) has its own GCM implementation for AES and PolarSSL can work fine with OpenSSL in return.

The GCM mode of encryption for AES requires specific GCM-related parameters. The current NodeJS API cannot provide these values to OpenSSL. And as such the calls fail, but not with clean errors. (This is more of an OpenSSL issue than a NodeJS issue).

(StevenLoomen points the reason  out in the comments as well, but I'd like an answer for everybody to see)